# Gnuplot timefmt not working

Tags: gnuplot

I am working with gnuplot to show simple data on a graph.

My datafile (output.csv) looks like this:

```
14:06,30.947
14:07,34.476
```

The first column is **time** the second column is **data**.
To get this out in a graph i used these commands in gnuplot:

```
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set xdata time
set datafile separator ','
plot "output2.csv" using 1:2 with lines
```

Now when i do this my graph looks like this:
[image]

Now as you can see my x axis only takes the minutes not the hours.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set timefmt` command only tells gnuplot the format of your input data. To specify the time format of the x axis, you need to add

```
set format x "%H:%M"
```

So

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"
set datafile separator ','
plot "output2.csv" using 1:2 with lines
```

[image]